# makefile foreach stops at the first iteration

Tags: makefile, g++

I have a list of source files to be compiled. I select them from different directories/subdirectories and in the end I have a list. I thought I would use a foreach loop with eval/call/define.The command info works and the first pass of make sees all of them.

Here is the piece of relevant code of the makefile:

```
define cmp-one
$(info $2)
$2:$1
        $(CMP) $(CMP_FLGS) $(INCL) -c $1 -o $2
endef

$(foreach src_tmp,$(SRC),$(info $(src_tmp)))
$(foreach src_tmp,$(SRC),$(eval $(call cmp-one,$(src_tmp),$(src_tmp:%.cpp=%.o))))
```

Here is the screen output for a very simple case to reduce my issue to the clearest example (NB: the make files live in a directory, so you'll notice some ../):

```
make --debug -Bf makefile_proj_1


GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
Reading makefiles...
../src/proj_1/proj_1_f1.cpp
../src/proj_1/proj_1_f2.cpp
../src/proj_1/proj_1_f3.cpp
../src/main_proj_1.cpp
../src/proj_1/proj_1_f1.o
../src/proj_1/proj_1_f2.o
../src/proj_1/proj_1_f3.o
../src/main_proj_1.o
Updating goal targets....
Must remake target `../src/proj_1/proj_1_f1.o'.
g++-4.9 -std=c++11 -Wall -I../incl/top -I../incl/proj_1 -c ../src/proj_1/proj_1_f1.cpp -o ../src/proj_1/proj_1_f1.o
Successfully remade target file `../src/proj_1/proj_1_f1.o'.
```

Only the first file gets compiled. If I shuffle the elements of the list of files, only the first one gets done (except for main, of course, because the other guys are not compiled). The inclusion of the $(info)'s does not cause any troubles.

I have tried other alternatives unsuccessfully, or simple things, like adding ; (desperation). I also looked in the GNU manual and around for a day, but no success. I came across .SECONDEXPANSION, but couldn't make it work either.

Does anyone know what basic error I am doing? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The issue here is that only one of your files gets compiled? Do you have a target that requires all of the output files? The default target for make is the first listed target.That's going to be the first file in `$(SRC)` if that's your entire makefile. Try adding `.PHONY: all` and `all: $(SRC:.cpp=.o)` to the top of the makefile and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awesome, Etan! Yep. It works. I put it right after .PHONY. That 'all' target, indeed, I had removed it some time in the past hours, thinking to 'concentrate' on the loop itself. I have learned for sure a basic thing not to forget again about how make works! Thanks.

Comment: Dont forget you can "accept" your own answer to close the question.